# displaying user inputs using pointers c++

Tags: c++

Help me to know what is wrong with it because i'm just a beginner, I'm trying to build a program that ask the user to enter short sentences until the user quit and display them in reverse order:
example
user enter:

```
My name is Todd
I like to travel
```

and display like that:

```
I like to travel
My name is Todd
```

Anyone can help me to make it work right;
It works right but does not pause it exit right away after execution. I want to be able to hold on the window.
Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int SIZE = 500;
    char input[SIZE];

    // collection that will hold our lines of text
    vector<string> lines;
    do
    {   // prompt the user
        cout << "Enter a short sentence(<enter> to exit): ";
        cin.getline(input,SIZE);
        if (!getline(cin, input) || input.empty())
            break;
        lines.push_back(input);
    } while (true);

    // send back to output using reverse iterators
    //  to switch line order.
    copy(lines.rbegin(), lines.rend(),
         ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
      // assume the file to reverse-print is the first
    //  command-line parameter. if we don't have one
    //  we need to leave now.
    if (argc < 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // will hold our file data
    std::vector<char> data;

    // open file, turning off white-space skipping
    cin>>(argv[1]);
    cin.seekg(0, cin.end);
    size_t len = cin.tellg();
    cin.seekg(0, cin.beg);

    // resize buffer to hold (len+1) chars
    data.resize(len+1);
    cin.read(&data[0], len);
    data[len] = 0; // terminator

    // walk the buffer backwards. at each newline, send
    //  everything *past* it to stdout, then overwrite the
    //  newline char with a nullchar (0), and continue on.
    char *start = &data[0];
    char *p = start + (data.size()-1);
    for (;p != start; --p)
    {
        if (*p == '\n')
        {
            if (*(p+1))
                cout << (p+1) << endl;
            *p = 0;
        }
    }

    // last line (the first line)
    cout << p << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Looks like there is an exact duplicate by the author posted days ago.

Comment: @ David , now I'm having an issue with displaying pause , it works right but does not pause it exit right away after displaying!!

Comment: @Todd What do you mean by pause? Are you referring to the command prompt?

Comment: I mean when I test the program it works as I want but doesn't stop it exit right away I tried system(PAUSE) but doesn't work

Comment: `system("pause");`, not `system(PAUSE);`. if that doesn't work, try `while(1);`.

Comment: @David if he is using pipe redirection to run this, `cin.get()` won't be helpful. (maybe `system("pause");` neither.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by using `std::string` in place of `char input[SIZE]`. I also removed the `cin.getline` part in the loop because it's not really needed.

```
std::string input;

do {
    // cin.getline(input, SIZE); <-- removed this line
    if (!getline(cin, input) || input.empty())
       break;
    lines.push_back(input);
} while (true);
```

See a demo [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy%241673).

Comment: Thanks a lot , now it's working right but doesn't pause at the end when I run it!

Comment: @Todd Add `cin.get()` as the last statement to your main. See if it works.

Comment: it doesn't work as well!!

Comment: In terms of holding the window after execution ends, of course it doesn't.

Comment: @Todd Is your program still not working?

Comment: @Todd Add `cin.ignore()` above `cin.get()` if it's still not working for you.

Comment: @David yeah the problem is with holding the window!

Comment: yeah now it's working, I just deleted this line:

Comment: if (argc < 2)
return EXIT_FAILURE;

Comment: and added system("pause"); thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Now that you say it works fine... (May be you should consider adding this to your post, not just in comments)

what you need is to *hold on the window* after execution finishes.

Then, it's simple enough.

```
#include <cstdlib>
// whatever.....
int main(){
  ......//whatever 
   .......//foo
    .......//bar
  system("pause"); // hold the window
}
```

replacing `system()` with a dummy infinite loop should work as well, which saves `#include <cstdlib>` but consumes CPU time.

Comment: Utilizing the `system` function for a simple pause is a bit of an overkill.

Comment: @phoeagon Thanks I tried that at fisr time!